# compare the multiple columns from two different dataframes and map the values using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have two dataframes, where there is common column in both dataframes, on comparing the column values, if the values in both dataframes matches, new column should be added in one of these dataframes like below.

**df1:**

```
|other_col   | col_a    | col_b   | col_c | e_values |
|:----------:|:--------:|:-------:|:-----:|:--------:|
|a           | dog      | egg     | hi    |          |
|a           | s        | f       | good  |          |
|b           | t        | u       | bad   |          |
|c           | u        | r       | data1 |          |
|d           | v        | l       | data2 |          |
|b           | w        | h       | data3 |          |
```

**df2:**

```
|col_1  | col_2  | col_3  | e_values              |
|:-----:|:------:|:------:|:---------------------:|
|sales  | dog    | egg    | ['sales','dog','egg'] |
|call   | s      |   f    | ['call','s','f']      |
|hello  | v      |   l    | ['hello','v','l']     |
```

I have used the logic

df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2,  how='outer', left_on=["col_a","col_b"], right_on = ['col_1','col_2'])

**The output what I am getting:**

```
|other_col   | col_a    | col_b   | col_c | col_1 |e_values               |
|:----------:|:--------:|:-------:|:-----:|:-----:|:---------------------:|
|a           | dog      | egg     | hi    |       |                       |
|a           | s        | f       | good  |       |                       |
|b           | t        | u       | bad   |       |                       |
|c           | u        | r       | data1 |       |                       |
|d           | v        | l       | data2 |       |                       |
|b           | w        | h       | data3 |       |                       |
|            | dog      | egg     |       | sales | ['sales','dog','egg'] |
|            | s        | f       |       | call  | ['call','s','f']      |
|            | v        | l       |       | hello | ['hello','v','l']     |
```

In this, if the values in **df2[['col_2','col_3']]** matches with **df1[['col_a','col_b']]**, then new column called **e_values** should be added **in** **df1 with list of values exactly from df2

**expected output:**

```
|other_col   | col_a    | col_b   | col_c |e_values                         |
|:----------:|:--------:|:-------:|:-----:|:-------------------------------:|
|a           | dog      | egg     | hi    | ['sales','dog','egg']           |
|a           | s        | f       | good  | ['call','s','f']                |
|b           | t        | u       | bad   | no match, random list of values |
|c           | u        | r       | data1 | random values                   |
|d           | v        | l       | data2 | ['hello','v','l']               |
|b           | w        | h       | data3 | random values                   |
```

Comment: I do understand that those are not your real data. But you are making it harder for people to help you if you don't provide a copy-&-pastable [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). (Those are not _my_ instructions, btw., it's official SO material.)

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. [ask] [Help]

Comment: This example cannot be "cut & paste & run". You talk about "the logic what I used" but you don't justify your "should", hence "why, justified by documentation". (Seems like maybe you think "logic" means "code", it doesn't.) PS My comment mentions error messages because it is boilerplate. PS Please look at the formatted version of your post before you publish.. See edit help re block & inline format for code & quotes. Clarify via edits, not comments. PS Minimal includes input.

Comment: LEFT/RIGHT JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left/right (respectivey) table rows extended by NaNs. FULL JOIN (`how='outer'`) gives INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left & right table rows extended by NaNs. Always know what INNER JOIN is part of your left/right/full JOIN. PS Normally "outer join" is used to refer collectively to left, right & full joins. Using `how='outer'` for full join is a very poor language/library choice.

Comment: PS You don't give the expected output, you give a muddle of the expected output & unclear comments about it. PS See the edit help re table format. (It doesn't belong inside code block format.) (But you should not be using it, you should give "tabular initialization code" (code formatted in columns) in a code block as part of a [mre].)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2,  how='outer', left_on=["col_a"], right_on = ['col_2'])
df1 = df1.drop(columns=["col_1","col_2","col_3","e_values_x"])
df1 = df1.rename(columns={'e_values_y':'e_values'})
```

- Merged the dataframe according to the `col_a` and `col_1` columns using an outer join.
- Drop the unwanted columns
- Rename the column e_values as it was present in both the dataframe suffixing was automatically added to them during the merge.

Comment: no this will not suit my question, please see my edited question with data in table format, and help me with the solution

Comment: I think the approach is the same, you just need to change the name of the columns you wanna compare.

Comment: No it's not working. For example, for the first row in expected output, the correct output is as shown above ['sales', 'dog', 'cat'] as there is a match in the both columns 'dog' , but instead it gives some other random list of values.

Comment: I have updated the answer you can check it out now

Comment: again its not working. there should be comparison of values here, thats where I have no idea, how to compare and map the corresponding values

Comment: The values are being compared through outer join, I am getting the same as your expected output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237306/discussion-between-lakshika-parihar-and-beginner).